# I'm getting error in Guessing game in python

Tags: python

I tried to write a guessing game in python.. I wrote everything correct but still it's not showing even if I guess correct number

```
secret_number = 5
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
k = 0


while guess_count < guess_limit:
    K = input(print("guess the number"))
    guess_count = guess_count + 1
    if k == secret_number:
        print('you won')
else:
    print('try again')
```

Comment: Please post your code as text and not an image. Also provide what's *not right* about the output if you want meaningful answers. At a brief glance you're using an uppercase `K` for the input and a lowercase as the variable to check against. You're also comparing a `str` to an `int` in your if statement.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your problem is in your input line.

**Your code**

```
    K = input(print("guess the number"))
```

**Problems**

1. python is case-sensitive so `K` is not `k`. You are making another variable named `K` and not assigning to existing `k`.
2. you are calling print inside input, so you are printing `None` (which `print` returned). That should be `input("guess the number")`
3. input returns a string, and later in `if k == secret_number`, it's not really True because `'5'` is not `5` in python.

**Solution**

Seeing all the problems, that line should be

```
    k = int(input("guess the number"))
```

change the line, your program will work.

**working code**

```
secret_number = 5
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
k = 0


while guess_count < guess_limit:
    k = int(input("guess the number"))
    guess_count = guess_count + 1
    if k == secret_number:
        print('you won')
else:
    print('try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems:
Your else statment isn't correctly indented, and your K is capital.
Here is a working solution:

```py
#secret number
sn=5
#amount of guesses
gc=0
#guess limit
gl=3
k=0
while gc<gl:
  k=int(input("Guess the number"))
  gc+=1
  if k==sn:
    print("you won :)")
    break
  else:
    print("Try again:(")
```

[EDIT]
Also, try using `int(input())` instead of just input for number programs like this, as it makes it a proper number.
You also don't need a `print` statement inside of an `input`.
A string inside an `input` is printed as if `print()` was called

Answer (score 0):

```
guessname= "Elephant".capitalize()
enterguessname=""
guescount=0
guesslimit= 3
outofguess= False
while enterguessname != guessname and not outofguess:
    if guescount < guesslimit:
        enterguessname = input("Enter guess name: ").upper()
        guescount += 1
    else:
            outofguess= True
if outofguess:
    print("you lose and correct name is " + guessname)
else:
        print("Your answer is right and correct answer is " + 
guessname)
```